# Looping through checkbox and getting the Text in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make simple checkbox, and when a a checkbox is checked i want to display a toast with the checkbox text.

This is my code which i have tried but not working

```
 nextscreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.DSP);
                for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    v = layout.getChildAt(i);
                    if (v instanceof CheckBox) {
                        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                            String text = String.valueOf(((CheckBox) v).getText());

                            Log.d("@@@@@@@@@" , "somethinng" +text);

                    }

                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

This is my layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/customer_email_addnew_edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/DSP"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/toi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Times of India"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/danikjagran"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toi"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Times of India"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/htimes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/danikjagran"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Times of India"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/conntinue"
        android:text="continue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way i can loop through all checked checkbox and get the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you presented doesn't show a `Toast` but writes into log instead.

Try this:

```java
if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
    String text = String.valueOf(((CheckBox) v).getText());
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**UPDATE**

This way you won't have to iterate the subviews everytime:

```java
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox mToi;
    private android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox mDanikjagran;
    private android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox mHtimes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

        mToi = (android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.toi);
        mDanikjagran = (android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.danikjagran);
        mHtimes = (android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.htimes);

        // ...

        nextscreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mToi.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, mToi.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (mDanikjagran.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, mDanikjagran.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (mHtimes.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, mHtimes.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but do you have any other logic to do the same bit more  efficient.

Comment: @Firdoesh added an example